# Adding a custom validator for a new country

Tags: python, formencode

I am using FormEncode in Python http://formencode.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/national.html#module-formencode.national.

I am trying to add a custom postal code validator for Brazil.  I've read the documentation, but none of it seems to be helping.  Does anyone have any idea on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wants to know how to solve this using FormEncode, this is the solution I came up with

```
class BrazilZipValidator(validators.Regex):
messages = {
    'invalid': _('Please enter a valid code (nnnnn-nnn or nnnnnnnn)')
}
regex = re.compile(r'^([0-9]{8})$|^([0-9]{5}-[0-9]{3})$')
strip = True

def _to_python(self, value, state):
    self.assert_string(value, state)
    match = self.regex.search(value)
    if not match:
        raise formencode.Invalid(self.message('invalid', state), value, \
                                 state)
    return match.group()
```

Then attach this class to the validation object

```
national.PostalCodeInCountryFormat._vd.update({'BR': BrazilZipValidator})
```

Answer (score -2):

Model

```
[checkCountry(AllowCountry = "India,USA,SriLanka", ErrorMessage = ("Please choose a valid country eg.(India,USA,SriLanka"))]
public string Country { get; set; }
```

In Attribute copy paste this code and please change the namespace name to avoid the errors

```
using System.Linq;


namespace WebApp.Models
{
    public class checkCountryAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public String AllowCountry { get; set; }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object country, ValidationContext validationContext)

        {

            string[] myarr = AllowCountry.ToString().Split(',');

            if (myarr.Contains(country))

            {

                return ValidationResult.Success;

            }

            else

            {

                return new ValidationResult("Please choose a valid country eg.(India,USA,SriLanka)");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Student(Student submit)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Succesfully Submitted";
                return View("Student");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Definitely it will work

IF THIS CODE NOT WORKING PLEASE COMMENT IT BELOW

Comment: OP is using Python, not Java.